# 960 css framework

Tags: html, css, frameworks

Am evaluating 960 gs css framework for using on my site.
Does anyone knows any big company that uses this framework to there sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS framework is a fairly shallow thing: you can see if it works for you quite easily.  What would a big company have found out that you could not?  Usually looking for big customers is a way to learn more about the intangibles of a product, like supportibiliy, scalability, stability, etc.  Make your site with 960 and see how it looks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be basing your decision on whether big companies use it. You should have a look at the practicalities of the system itself via self testing and videos. http://www.youtube.com/user/theartofcode has some good videos on it to get u started.

The reason it is widely used is it can eliminate time by using predefined css to code ur div boxes based on 12 layout. All you need to do is look at how many columns out of the 960px you want to use for each element and name your divs accordingly.

You can also still style the divs easily enough because even though it has a div class of grid_12 etc. you can have multiple classes

look at the example code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_12 header">THIS IS THE PAGE HEADER</div>
<div class="grid_6">col 1</div>
<div class="grid_6">col 2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

u can easily code up a page which is centered, 960px wide and contains a header and 2 columns ready to go with minimal html. it also has a wrapping div(first container)

you could then change the header to a red background by putting .header{background:red;} into your main.css file

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [960.gs](http://960.gs/) home page and scroll down. There are many examples of established companies making use of the framework. I have used it myself in more than one product and it does a great job.

Comment: Yes offcourse..I have seen those sites..but what i was looking for was more established/big companies websites/applications that uses 960.

Comment: Why? Your decision to use 960 to assist your css development should not be affected by whether or not a big company is using it. It's so small and simple that there should be no more issue in using it than taking a snippet of code from somewhere to help in your general development. Ned (below) seems to have said the same thing...